# Get output of library google pagerank checker

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, pagerank

I use codeigniter and want use **Google PageRank Checker** (i get it from this site:[Using PHP to retrieve the Google Pagerank of any domain](http://lucdebrouwer.nl/using-php-to-retrieve-the-google-pagerank-of-any-domain/)) as library in codeigniter.

I done it in library as this(full code my library): http://pastebin.com/8TsiT9H4

Load this library in contorola as:

```
$this->load->library('googlepr');
```

And run it in view as following code:

```
$gpr = new GooglePR();
$pagerank = $gpr->getPagerank('http://www.domain.com');
echo $pagerank;
```

But it don't give me output, How can fix it and get output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the PHP-Curl bindings

Install PHP-Curl and all should be good. Tips [here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php)

Comment: Ok, i nstall PHP-Cur and there is not it error but when i echo output class in view as `$gpr = new GooglePR();
 $pagerank = $gpr->getPagerank('http://www.domain.com');
 echo $pagerank;` it don't have output. How is fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix here unless you find what's wrong with that function:

```
function getPagerank($url) {
    $query = "http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&ch=" . $this->CheckHash($this->HashURL($url)) . "&features=Rank&q=info:" . $url . "&num=100&filter=0";
    echo "<br> query: $query </br>";
    $data = $this->file_get_contents_curl($query);
    $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
    echo "<br> pos: $pos </br>";
    if($pos !== false){
        $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
    echo "<br> pagerank: $pagerank </br>";      
        return trim($pagerank);
    }
}
```

It gives that output in my web server

> query:
>   http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&ch=791322981365&features=Rank&q=info:http://www.google.com&num=100&filter=0
>
> pos:  NULL

So, i think function is outdated.

Comment: This line isn't working anymore: $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_"); Probably google has changed something and i don't know how you can "done" it by that script. Probably you can't unless you can find a new script which isn't outdated